# Ruby/ Rails: undefined method `set' for ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activejob

I created a job like so:

```
class SendEmailJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

   def perform(user)
    @user = user
    UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_later
   end

end
```

That uses my mailer:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    mg_client = Mailgun::Client.new ENV['api_key']
    message_params = {
      :from   => ENV["gmail_username"],
      :to     => @user.email,
      :subject => "Welcome",
      :text =>    "This is a welcome email"
    }
    mg_client.send_message ENV["domain"], message_params
  end

end
```

My controller:

```
  SendEmailJob.set(wait: 20.seconds).perform_later(@user)
```

I keep getting the following error:
NoMethodError (undefined method `set' for SendEmailJob:Class):

EDIT config/application.rb
require File.expand_path('../boot', **FILE**)

```
require 'rails/all'
require 'active_job'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module LinkbuilderPro
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end
```

Rails 4.1.8

Comment: can you show your   config/application.rb` file? also, what is your Rails version?

Comment: @ojdq s answer should work, there is a blog post on how to do the same in engineyard https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/getting-started-with-active-job. However I'm more interested to see your stack trace if possible ( so that I can try to track which file gives this error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveJob was integrated with Rails from version `4.2`

Before that, you needed to use the `active_job` gem. As you are using Rails version `4.1.8`, you have to use the `active_job` gem along with the old syntaxes. `.set` method was not available before Rails 4.2, so you are getting that error.

However, the syntax for Rails version 4.1 is:

```
YourJob.enqueue(record)
YourJob.enqueue(record, options)
```

So, in your case, it would be something like:

```
SendEmailJob.enqueue(@user, wait: 20.seconds)
```

`perform_later` is introduced in Rails 4.2

See [this article](http://kinopyo.com/en/blog/use-activejob-in-rails-4-1) for the active job differences between Rails 4.1 and 4.2

Comment: I had to use SendEmailJob.enqueue(@user)

Comment: right. As you are using Rails 4.1.8, this is the correct syntaxt. 2nd param is an options hash. You don't send it, if you don't need it.

Comment: @josh please consider upvoting/accepting the answer if that helped you to solve your problem. Thanks.

Comment: To see how accepting answers work: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your controller:

```
SendEmailJob.new(@user).enqueue(wait: 20.seconds)
```

Comment: Do I need to change my def perform(user) action in my send_email_job.rb  to new(user)? Getting a ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0).

Comment: In my case I do:

class SendEmailJob < ActiveJob::Base 
      queue_as :email
      def perform(email) 
           UserMailer.follow_up_email(email).deliver_now
      end 
end

In controller:
def create
   @user = User.create(user_params)       
   SendEmailJob.new(@user.email).enqueue(wait: 20.seconds) 
   redirect_to root_url
end