# undefined method for `perform_later' on an ApplicationJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

Running Rails 7 and creating a simple job that extends `ApplicationJob`, the `perform` method works, but not the `perform_later`.  Do I need to install a queuing backend for that method to work?

In `app/jobs/simple_file_write_test_job.rb` :

```
  1 class SimpleFileWriteTestJob < ApplicationJob
  2   queue_as :default
  3 
  4   def perform(*args)
  5     f = File.open("/tmp/project_job_test.txt", "a")
  6     f.puts("#{self.job_id}: #{DateTime.now}")
  7     f.close
  8   end
  9 end
```

`perform` works:

```
irb(main):003:0> reload!; j = SimpleFileWriteTestJob.new; j.perform()
Reloading...                                            
=> nil
```

I can see the file got written to:

```
/opt/project-web # tail -f /tmp/project_job_test.txt 

e82cf2d1-f480-4bdc-bef2-975b084fe68d: 2022-07-12T19:10:53+00:00
```

But trying to run `perform_later` :

```
irb(main):004:0> reload!; j = SimpleFileWriteTestJob.new; j.perform_later()
Reloading...
(irb):4:in `<main>': undefined method `perform_later' for #<SimpleFileWriteTestJob:0x00007f6b007f0f90 @arguments=[], @job_id="07a747ad-fef7-4d28-8bd5-66ac7e31e2ac", @queue_name="default", @priority=nil, @executions=0, @exception_executions={}, @timezone="UTC"> (NoMethodError)                                                 
                                                                                       
reload!; j = SimpleFileWriteTestJob.new; j.perform_later()                             
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                               
Did you mean?  perform
```

This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32217343/1611925) says `active-job` is included starting from Rails 4.2.  So I'm assuming I don't need it in the gem file.

Running Rails 7:

```
irb(main):005:0> Rails.version
=> "7.0.3"
```

Feels like I'm missing something embarrassingly simple.

Comment: It appears that `perform_later` is a "class method" https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#enqueue-the-job and https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Enqueuing/ClassMethods.html#method-i-perform_later so you should be able to call `SimpleFileWriteTestJob.perform_later`

Comment: `SimpleFileWriteTestJob.perform_later(j)`

Answer (score 0):

@dbugger had the right answer in the comments of the question.  As @engineersmnky stated, `perform_later` is a class method:

```
irb(main):010:0> reload!; j = SimpleFileWriteTestJob.new; SimpleFileWriteTestJob.perform_later(j)
Reloading...
Enqueued SimpleFileWriteTestJob (Job ID: 4d562bed-6336-4ccb-8325-f16e1bffec36) to Async(default)
=>                                                                                          
#<SimpleFileWriteTestJob:0x00007f6aff855180                                                 
 @arguments=[],                                                                             
 @exception_executions={},                                                                  
 @executions=0,                                                                             
 @job_id="4d562bed-6336-4ccb-8325-f16e1bffec36",                                            
 @priority=nil,                                                                             
 @provider_job_id="8fd297e3-eeaf-474b-984b-0ff7c66113db",                                   
 @queue_name="default",                                                                     
 @successfully_enqueued=true,                                                               
 @timezone="UTC">                                                                           
irb(main):011:0> Performing SimpleFileWriteTestJob (Job ID: 4d562bed-6336-4ccb-8325-f16e1bffec36) from Async(default) enqueued at 2022-07-12T19:24:57Z
Performed SimpleFileWriteTestJob (Job ID: 4d562bed-6336-4ccb-8325-f16e1bffec36) from Async(default) in 12.25ms
```

Here's hoping they clarify the [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html).

Comment: You can skip the first step (`j = SimpleFileWriteTestJob.new`) and just call `SimpleFileWriteTestJob.perform_later`. `perform_later` uses argument forwarding so it does the first step for you in `job_or_instantiate`.